# How to filter heights using LAScatalog in lidR

Tags: r, lidar, lidr

I would like to filter the points that are used in a canopy height model. In particular I would like filter out any points whose height is over 200 feet. I've tried the code below but when I plot the difference between my normalized and filtered tiles, they are exactly the same and there are still z values above 200 feet. I must be using the `opt_filter` command incorrectly, or have chosen the wrong mechanism.

```
library(lidR)

indata <- suppressWarnings(readLAScatalog ("c:/test/laz"))

# Normalize point cloud data
opt_output_files(indata) <- "c:/test/norm/norm_{XRIGHT}_{YBOTTOM}"
normalized_las <- normalize_height (indata, tin(), na.rm=TRUE)

# Keep points where height is between 0 and 200 feet
filtered_las <- suppressWarnings(readLAScatalog ("c:/test/norm/"))
opt_filter (filtered_las) <- "Z>=0 and Z<=200"
opt_output_files(filtered_las) <- "c:/test/filt/filt_{XRIGHT}_{YBOTTOM}"
filt_ctg <- catalog_retile(filtered_las)

# Now read in the same filtered and normalized tile
filt1 <- 'c:/test/filt/filt_2885000_2320000.las'
filtlas <- readLAS(filt1)
norm1 <- 'c:/test/norm/norm_2885000_2320000.las'
normlas <- readLAS(norm1)

# Visualize difference between filtered and unfiltered points
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
boxplot(normlas@data$Z, ylim = c(-10,1000), ylab = "Height (ft)", main = "Before Filtering")
boxplot(filtlas@data$Z, ylim = c(-10,1000), ylab = "Height (ft)", main = "After Filtering")
hist(normlas@data$Z, xlim=c(-2,1000), xlab = "Height (ft)", main = "Before Filtering")
hist(filtlas@data$Z, xlim=c(-2,1000), xlab = "Height (ft)", main = "After Filtering")
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mistaking the argument `filter` in `readLAS()` and the function `filter_poi()`.

#### `filter_poi()`

When you have read a LAS file in R and the point cloud is already loaded, you can use a classical R syntax, that you are likely to be familiar with because `dplyr` popularize it a lot, to select some points of interest (POI)

```r
las = readLAS(LASfile)
las = filter_poi(las, Z>=0, Z<=200)
```

#### `filter` argument in `readLAS()`

`readLAS` can take an optional parameter `filter` and allows selection of “rows” (or points) **while reading** the LAS file. It happens at C++ level and not at the R level. It is better for different reasons that are documented in `readLAS()` and in [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lidR/vignettes/lidR-LAS-class.html). But because it does not happen at R level, R syntax does not work. Instead you have to use predefined set of commands. List of commands can be printed using `readLAS(filter = "-help")`. You can do:

```r
las = readLAS(LASfile, filter = "-drop_z_below 0 -drop_z_above 200")
```

#### `opt_filter()`

When processing a `LAScatalog` you do not call `readLAS()` yourself. It is called internally.`opt_filter()` is used to propagate the information:

```r
opt_filter(ctg) = "-drop_z_below 0 -drop_z_above 200"
```

#### Other `filter`

For the sake of comprehensiveness I must also speak about the other `filter` argument you can find in `lidR` such as in `grid_metrics()` or `segment_shapes()`. Those `filter` arguments are R-based filters and thus expect R syntax. They allow for processing a subset of the point-cloud without creating a copy of the point-cloud unlike with `filter_poi()`. They correspond to clever memory optimization but cannot exist for every function.

```r
metrics = grid_metrics(las, ~mean(Z), 20, filter = ~Z>=0 & Z<=200)
```

#### Summary

1. Use `readLAS(... filter = "-command")` whenever you can (i.e. when it exists a command that do what you want to do) to do not load in R the points you don't need.
2. Use `filter = R expression` if you want to use `filter_poi()` but the function you are using is capable of being smarter than that.
3. Use `filter_poi()` the other cases.
4. Read the [LAS formal class vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lidR/vignettes/lidR-LAS-class.html) and/or the [first chapter](https://jean-romain.github.io/lidRbook/io.html#read) of the lidR book.