# Filtering out points above maximum height minus 10 in LidR

Tags: las, lidr

I am trying to create a trunk density dataset by removing ground points and canopy points from a forest lidar dataset. My goal is to use the filter_poi tool to remove any points below 1.5 meters from the normalized las that I created, and then remove canopy points by filtering out any points that are 5 meters below the tallest point and above.

I tried `filter_poi(nlas,Z<=1.5,Z>=X-5)` but that doesn't seem to work despite not throwing any errors.

I now realize that the equation I want should be something like `filter_poi(nlas,Z<=1.5,Z>=Z-MAX-5)` however i dont know how to specify the max value as it would need to be within a confined cell.

Is there a way to use a DSM to set the max height and select point that are a set number of units below the DSM?

Comment: See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387630/how-to-filter-heights-using-lascatalog-in-lidr

Comment: How did you define 'X' prior to the filter_poi() call? Share the rest of your script and any errors please.

Comment: Here X is the X coordinates of the points. Z > X - 5 means for each point keep those with Z superior to X - 5 which should return 0 points.