# How do I run filter_poi() on a LAScatalog object?

Tags: r, lidr

I want to read a LAS catalog, create a DEM, normalize the catalog, and run filter_poi() on the catalog.

My issue is that when I try to run filter_poi(), in the code below, I get the error "Argument is not a LAS object." Is there a way to run filter_poi() on a LAScatalog?

```
# Read LAScatalog
ctg <- readLAScatalog("__folder__\\tiled\\")

# Create DEM
dem<-grid_terrain(ctg, res=5, algorithm = knnidw(), overwrite=T)

# Set output files location
opt_output_files(ctg) <- "\\___folder___\\{ORIGINALFILENAME}"

# Normalize height
norm<-normalize_height(ctg, dem)

veg_canopy<-filter_poi(norm, Z>4 & Z<120 & Classification==5)
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to filter these points which would imply creating a new copy of your collection of files. You can simply keep or discard points at read time.

```r
readLAS("file.las", filter = "-drop_z_below 4 -drop_z_above 120 -keep_class 5")
```

---

btw `grid_terrain` is deprecated and does not have argument `overwrite`

Comment: Thank you! This answer combined with your response from [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387630/how-to-filter-heights-using-lascatalog-in-lidr) leads me to think I need to use the opt-filter() function in order to apply the <filter = "..."> method to a LAScatalog. Does this sound right?

Comment: Absolutely. If you want to  keep or discard points at read time with a LAScatalog you can use `opt_filter()` to  propagate the `filter` to `readLAS` internally.

Comment: Awesome, that worked! Thank you so much. Before I mark the answer correct, could you add that to the answer possibly?